# Using a custom identity provider in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-jpa

In my current project, we store user login info inside a MongoDB collection. We would like to implement an authentication mechanism that checks the credentials from a request against the information stored in said MongoDB. There is a tutorial for doing this [with JPA + Postgres](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-getting-started) but there is no information on using MongoDB in the same capacity. I suspect that I would need to write a custom IdentityProvider for this case. I tried using the JPA identity provider as a base, but it looks like the security-jpa source code contains only [an abstract identity provider](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/4228a370eeec6df2282f19536fcec180a5955d4a/extensions/security-jpa/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/security/jpa/runtime/JpaIdentityProvider.java), while the [actual provider is generated automatically using black magic](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/4228a370eeec6df2282f19536fcec180a5955d4a/extensions/security-jpa/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/security/jpa/deployment/QuarkusSecurityJpaProcessor.java#L140). Has anyone ever had success adapting the existing Quarkus security architecture to MongoDB or anything else that is not covered by security-jpa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I was able to get a custom `IdentityProvider` to work. Here's a very simple demo (without any MongoDB logic):

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class DemoIdentityProvider implements IdentityProvider<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationRequest> {
    private static final Map<String, String> CREDENTIALS = Map.of("bob", "password124", "alice", "hunter2");

    @Override
    public Class<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationRequest> getRequestType() {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationRequest.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationRequest request,
                                              AuthenticationRequestContext authenticationRequestContext) {
        if (new String(request.getPassword().getPassword()).equals(CREDENTIALS.get(request.getUsername()))) {
            return Uni.createFrom().item(QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder()
                .setPrincipal(new QuarkusPrincipal(request.getUsername()))
                .addCredential(request.getPassword())
                .setAnonymous(false)
                .addRole("admin")
                .build());
        }
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException("password invalid or user not found");
    }
}
```

Note that in order to access `QuarkusSecurityIdentity`, the `quarkus-security` extension needs to be included as dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore, `quarkus.http.auth.basic=true` needs to be added to `application.properties` for the identity provider be used with basic auth.

Comment: Sure, a similar pattern can be followed for MongoDB collections